# Caching ASP.NET server controls for a specified time

Tags: asp.net, caching

I have a server control which has a lot of controls on it. The data source of those controls gets refreshed once a day. I want to cache the whole control for 24 hours and as soon as the data source of the controls gets refreshed, I want to refresh the server control as well. I know there is a cache duration attribute under OutputCache tag, but that wont work for me. Is there a method by which I can cache the server control say at 6 AM every day. Using in-memory cache too is not an option for me.

Thanks
Vijay

Comment: You can use the database to store your cached server controls and update them after each 24 hours.

Comment: Is there any other way to do so rather than caching the server control in the DB

Comment: If you dont want to use the in memory cache then it is the only viable option available(Not sure).

Answer (score 0):

To cache whole control / page you should choose **Output cache**. To use it just add this directive and set cache duration in minutes in *Duration* property:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="60" VaryByParamarybyparam="None" %>
```

Example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="testWebApplication.WebForm1" %>
<%@ OutputCache Duration="60" VaryByParamarybyparam="None" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Caching</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

However you can cache only the data from datasource using [Application caching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18c1wd61(v=vs.140).aspx).